# url rewriting with railo tomcat apache for cf wheels

Tags: apache, tomcat, mod-rewrite, railo, cfwheels

I am new to [cf wheels](http://cfwheels.org/) and would like to enable url rewriting. I have my wheels folder on a subdirectory at the root of my host.

I believe I have my .htaccess file set up correctly but don't have the proper apache settings to enable url rewriting.
What settings would I need to mess with and how would I go about doing so?

Comment: for real... nobody can help me out?

Comment: If mod_rewrite is installed (it usually is with Apache), then you turn re-writing on with `RewriteEngine on`. Also, there is documentation on the cfwheels website - if this doesn't solve your problems you may want to get on the [cfwheels mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/cfwheels) - they'll be able to help determine if it's a cfwheels issue or a more general rewrite/config issue.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the instructions in the [cfwheels url-rewriting documentation](http://cfwheels.org/docs/1-1/chapter/url-rewriting)

If these don't work, update your question to indicate what parts succeed and where it fails, and post the relevant parts of your config files.